# I can’t load all documents from csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana

i'm trying to load csv file to Elasticsearch using python

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import csv

# Elastic search configuation

es = Elasticsearch('http://IP:8081')

# Creating index
es.indices.create(index="suivipsi")

# Looking if the index exists
#es.indices.exists(index="firstindex")

# Open csv file and bulk upload
  with open('Suivi_des_PSI_2.csv',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='suivipsi')
```

my csv file hase 8763 line bunt when index is created in elasticsearch it gives that only 334 lignes are loaded to index
as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UxsF.png)

Comment: You first need to convert this CSV to JSON, as Elastic expects to get a JSON structure not a CSV

Comment: @NetanelMalka but elasticsearch can also read csv files

Comment: Have you tried explicitly unpacking the elements of `DictReader`? The reader only implements `__next__` so a `helpers.bulk(es, list(reader), index="…")` could do the trick.